# How sysupgrade a firmware in Openwrt with "--no-reboot" option?

Tags: upgrade, reboot, openwrt, firmware

Is it possible to run "sysupgrade" a firmware in openwrt without reboot? I need to upgrade a new firmware without rebooting.

Thanks.

Comment: Without a reboot, the upgrade would not be effective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I need reboot to let the upgrade be effective, but I would reboot the system manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not feasible. When upgrading, the underlying filesystem is replaced entirely. To do this without crashing the system/programs, the upgrade process first kills all other processes, then switches to a temporary RAM filesystem to perform the actual flash writing. Of course, you could keep the router running like that, but it can no longer perform meaningful operation.

With more RAM, one could copy the entirety of the flash filesystem to RAM first, allowing all services to keep running. However, routers are typically very low on pretty much all resources.

Comment: Thanks for your return. However,I would like to do the upgrade process in two step manually. The first one is the flashing and the second is the reboot process. There is a method like that ?

Comment: I believe my answer addresses just that: Theoretically yes, practically no—especially because the router can no longer perform meaningful operation after flashing. There is simply no point.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your answer.